# CTE in sql server return empty value but not NULL issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

This is the classic question : Write a SQL query to get the second highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the query should return 200 as the second highest salary. If there is no second highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
| 200                 |
+---------------------+
```

I use CTE to solve this in SQL server:

```
with Emp_Rank AS
(select Salary, row_number()over(order by Salary) as Salrank
from Employee)
Select Salary as SecondHighestSalary
from Emp_Rank
where Emp_Rank.Salrank = 2
```

The answer is not accepted, showing below. I figure the [] vs [null] is the problem but I don't know why or how to solve it.

Input
{"headers": {"Employee": ["Id", "Salary"]}, "rows": {"Employee": [[1, 100]]}}
Output
{"headers": ["SecondHighestSalary"], "values": []}
Expected
{"headers":["SecondHighestSalary"],"values":[[null]]}

Ps, I used Max() to solve this with no problem. null wasn't an issue there. (why?)

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt looks good to me - you just need to order the salary in descending order rather than ascending:

```
with emp_rank as (
    select salary, row_number()over(order by salary desc) as salrank
    from employee
)
select salary as secondhighestsalary
from emp_rank
where salrank = 2
```

Depending on how you want to handle ties, you might want to use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` (this would return the second distinct highest value, even if there are ties in the first or second position).

If you don't care about ties, note that you could get the same result in a simpler manner with an `fetch` clause:

```
select salary as secondhighestsalary
from employee
order by salary desc
offset 1 row fetch next 1 row only
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the simpler manner! And I added desc in my code but it's still returning as wrong. Think it's expecting [null] as the output. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate what GMB has provided, with respect both solution fails the test case of [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/).

```
with sal(salary, rnk) as 
         (select salary,dense_rank() over( order by Salary desc  )  as rnk from Employee)
    select max(salary) as SecondHighestSalary  from sal where rnk=2;
```

The trick here is:MAX returns NULL when there is no row to select.
There are solutions with case statements that works for Mysql but with t-sql it's it tricky.

```
select nullif(salary,'') as SecondHighestSalary  from sal where rnk=2;
```

Ideally, this should work,but it seems to represent  blank,' ' is not sufficient. Many have used count function as work around,again it's just doing some analytical, dual computations under the hood similar to what max() does.

More than happy, if someone can make nullif working on this problem.